# 2.5x atmospheric pressure + 25% atmospheric oxygen saturation level =?

Tags: planets, atmosphere, life, oxygen

So my question is pretty much as the title states, what would be the effects on the human body with these atmospheric conditions? More specifically, how would effect the growth of land mammals, reptiles, birds, and vegetation?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, GuyversLab, while your question is concise. Its brevity makes it puzzling. Does this situation exist on Earth or another planet? Oxygen at high pressure becomes toxic. At 2.5 atmospheres, this is close to the lethal limit.  Please expand your question to give more context to enable cogent answers.

Answer (score 6):

Normal atmosphere is about **101.325 kPa** so $101.325 \text{ kPa} \times 2.5$ would be **253.3125 kPa**.

Normal oxygen concentration is 20.946% but you want a 25% more O<sub>2</sub> so it would be **26.1825%**.

Now we have to calculate the partial pressure of oxygen to know if this is breathable, I don't want to make much calculations so I will only think about the 3 most important gas in our atmosphere (if you want tomorrow I can improve the answer) (with *low precision values* I mean an error of ~1%):

$$\begin{array}{|c|cc|ccc|c|} 
\hline
 & \text{Earth} & \text{Your world} & \text{gr/mol} & \text{Mols} & \text{Fractal Mol} & \text{Partial Pressure} \\ \hline
\text{N}_2 & 78.08\% & 73.99\% & 28.0134 & 2.64 & 0.75 & 192.19 \space\text{kPa} \\ \hline
\text{O}_2 & 20.95\% & 26.18\% & 31.9988 & 0.81 & 0.23 & 59.53 \space\text{kPa} \\ \hline
\text{Ar} & 0.93\% & 0.86\% & 39.948 & 0.02 & 0.006 & 1.58 \space\text{kPa} \\ \hline
\textbf{Total} & & & & 3.48 & & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

O<sub>2</sub> partial pressure is **59.53 kPa**, so... What does this mean? Well... at 50 kPa you enter into [**oxygen toxicity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity) basically you will die in some hour or maybe days.

All the life of your planet would be faster and have a higher metabolic rate, animals would have problems with oxidation (they will slowly rot) and they will age faster ([oxygen free radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_oxygen_species)). Also, your insect would be much larger. Insects haven't **our** air-breathing respiratory system like other animals, they **breath through their skin** `*`, they can't be bigger because they won't have enough surface per gramme of *insect* to breathing. With more O<sub>2</sub> insect could have bigger bodies without suffocating.

**In [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/82850/35041) I explain better the effects of high and low levels of oxygen.**

## *

> Insect respiration is accomplished **without lungs**. Instead, the insect respiratory system uses a system of **internal tubes and sacs** through which gases either diffuse or are actively pumped, **delivering oxygen directly to tissues that need it via their trachea**. Since oxygen is delivered directly, the circulatory system is **not used to carry oxygen**, and is therefore greatly reduced. [...] Air is taken in through openings on the sides of the abdomen called spiracles. 
> The respiratory system is an **important factor that limits the size of insects**. **As insects get bigger, this type of oxygen transport gets less efficient** and thus the heaviest insect currently weighs less than 100 g. However, with **increased atmospheric oxygen levels**, as happened in the late Paleozoic, **larger insects were possible,** such as dragonflies with wingspans of more than two feet.

Comment: Insects most certainly have a respiratory system; it is indeed very different from other land animals, in that it is made up of a network of tubes called _trachaeas_, connected to the exterior air by _spiracles_, which distribute oxygen directly to the tissues; their haemolymph does not carry oxygen. But you are right in that this kind of system cannot support larger animals unless the partial pressure of oxygen is much higher than on earth.

Comment: @AlexP I'd be ok with a rewording of "they don't have a respiratory system like other air-breathing animals." Ender correctly simplifies their system to "breathing through their skin" which is the important detail here.

Comment: @AlexP I know that they have respiratory system, I put that they haven't because it's more easy for understand to a normal person.

Comment: @Draco18s I have already edited my post. sorry if I confused someone.

Comment: More "politically correct" than "confusing." No harm done (although Alex could've just edited it himself). :)

Comment: @Draco18s: *They do not breathe through their skin*. Their "skin" is an impermeable cuticle overlaying the surface of their exoskeleton. They have a respiratory system which takes air through holes, just like ours, but then distributes the air directly to the tissues, unlike other animals which carry oxygen and carbon dioxyde in their blood. And I seldom edit other people's text; the right of the author to the integrity of their text is both unlimited in time and inalienable.

Comment: @AlexP To which I say, "Gosh, if I simplify that for the sake of saying why insects can only get so big without getting technical because all that matters is the Red-Circle / Yellow-Square mental model, that sounds an awful lot like 'they breath through their skin.'" And again, it would have been super easy for you to adjust the wording of the answer when you edited in the latex.

Comment: @AlexP, if you want to improve my post or if you want that I improve my own post you can tell me, I only tryied to make easy for understand, maybe Guyvers Lab doesn't want to know **how** insects breath so I didn't explain it, but if you want I can do that.

Comment: @Draco18s: I believe this is a good answer; you already have a +1 from me. I would just replace the jarring "they breathe through their skin" with "which scales proportionally to their surface" or something similar. But it's not essential.

Comment: @AlexP, I have added a quote of Wikipedia about insect's respiratory system.